# Two-way connection between a PC and Pi via Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, communication, robotics

I'm planning to establish an ethernet connection between a PC and a robot(with the Pi on it and the robot and PC being around 30ft apart). I would like to use the Pi to control operations onboard(Pi connected to cameras and controlling an arduino onboard which controls thrusters/sevos on the bot). I’d also like to use the Rpi to send back the video data from the cameras to the PC.

Basically, my question is, is it possible to get information flowing both ways? If I use an ethernet cable to connect the PC to the Pi would I then be able to get the video feed back to the PC? If not, what can I do to achieve both of these goals?

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet implements a layer 1 / layer 2 protocol and can be used in full duplex mode.

You can send ANY DATA over the Ethernet connection. Most commonly TCP/IP is used and can be used to transfer data, but the protocol depends on your requirements and UDP is more suited to real time data.

Comment: Is Ethernet full-duplex by default or is any additional setup required?